# Resizing 2D char array causes exception

Tags: c, pointers, malloc, realloc

I'm new to C, so please forgive me for noobie mistakes, we all need to start somewhere.

My task is to get some lines from a big file and store each line in a 2d array, where `li[0]` is the first line and so on...

On top of that, I have no ideia whats the size of this 'big text', so I came up with the code bellow to resize the array every time it reaches critical size (is there an easier way to do that?). Also, I could not find a better way to define the line size other than setting it very high.

The code bellow fails on the second time it resizes with an exception on this line `char **temp = realloc(lin, LINE_QUANT * sizeof(char*));`

Whats causing that exception?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define LINE_TAM 200

size_t PAL_QUANT = 100, LINE_QUANT = 3;

int main(){
    int i = 0;
    char **li = (char**) malloc(LINE_QUANT * sizeof(char*));
    char fname[30];
    FILE *arq = NULL;

    // alloc word container
    for (i=0; i < LINE_QUANT; i++)
        li[i] = malloc(LINE_TAM * sizeof(char));

    if(li == NULL) return 0;

    //(ommited file opener)

    i = 0;

    //getting words from file (unknown size)
    while(fgets(li[i], LINE_TAM, arq) != NULL){
        while(i >= LINE_QUANT - 1) resizeArr(li);
        i++;
    }


return 1;
}

void resizeArr(char **lin){
    int i;
    LINE_QUANT = LINE_QUANT * 2;
    char **temp = realloc(lin, LINE_QUANT * sizeof(char*));
    if(temp) {
        lin = temp;
        for (i = LINE_QUANT/2; i < LINE_QUANT; i++){
            lin[i] = malloc(LINE_TAM * sizeof(char*));
            if (lin[i] == NULL)
                exit(1);
        }
    }
    else
        exit(1);

    free(temp);
}
```

Comment: Ask yourself why `realloc` returns a value. Could it possibly be specified similarly to `resizeArr`? After all, `resizeArr` is just `realloc` with some additions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since each element of the array will be the same size, use could be made of a pointer to array, `(*li)[LINE_TAM]`.
Because `resizeArr` modifies the pointer, either a pointer to the pointer needs to be passed to the function or the function needs to return the pointer.
`realloc` will take care of any required `free`, so do not free the pointers.
This uses `stdin` but it can be modified to use a `FILE*`.
Enter `stop` to exit the loop.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define LINE_TAM 200

void resizeArr ( size_t *line_quant, char (**lin)[LINE_TAM]);

int main(){
    int i = 0;
    char (*li)[LINE_TAM] = NULL;//pointer to array
    size_t Line_Quant = 3;

    // alloc word container
    if ( NULL == ( li = malloc( sizeof *li * Line_Quant))) {
        fprintf ( stderr, "malloc problem\n");
        return 1;
    }

    i = 0;

    //getting words from file (unknown size)
    while ( fgets ( li[i], LINE_TAM, stdin) != NULL) {
        if ( 0 == strcmp ( li[i], "stop\n")) {
            break;
        }
        if (i >= Line_Quant - 1) {
            resizeArr ( &Line_Quant, &li);
        }
        i++;
    }

    free ( li);

    return 1;
}

void resizeArr ( size_t *line_quant, char (**lin)[LINE_TAM]) {
    int i;
    char (*temp)[LINE_TAM] = realloc ( *lin, sizeof **lin * *line_quant * 2);
    if ( temp) {//success
        *lin = temp;//assign back to caller
        *line_quant *= 2;//increase by two
        for ( i = *line_quant / 2; i < *line_quant; i++) {
            (*lin)[i][0] = 0;
        }
    }
    else {
        fprintf ( stderr, "realloc problem\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. Why multiply later the line_quant var though? Also, is there any particular reason not to use LINE_QUANT as a global var?